# Map Issue In iOS 6

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

In iOS 5 this worked fine, and I was under the impression that everything from MKMapKit would continue working in much the same way.  However, instead of zooming to my location and adding annotations that I have set up, it just shows North America.  I am leaving the annotations out of the code snippet I have, and just putting in the initial code setup.

```
[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeSatellite];
[mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
[mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
mapView.delegate = self;
MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
region.center.latitude = 32.385325 ;
region.center.longitude = -86.217442;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.005f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.005f;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

Any thoughts on why it is not zooming to where I have it set?

Comment: Is it not zooming at all, or is it zooming somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally don't suspect an iOS 6 v iOS 5 issue. This code works fine for me in iOS 6. So the problem rests elsewhere.

In short, a problem with the `mapView` variable seems far more likely. Have you checked to see that `mapView` is not `nil`? There are all sorts of simple candidate issues:

- Perhaps you manually declared class instance variable for a property (which you should not do ... simply define your property and let the compiler synthesize your instance variable for you, precisely to avoid this sort of possible confusion); or
- Perhaps there was a failure to link up the `IBOutlet`, etc.

Comment: That was it.  Had it as an ivar and property.  Removed the property and worked fine.  Thx